# Add an existing entity instead of creating new entity in a many-to-many relationship in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have Book entity and Author entity having many-to-many relationship. I have a book like this: (**author A has id=1** in database and I use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) so I don't want to add id)

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Spring Boot 1"
  "authors": [
     {
        "name": "A"
     }
  ]
}
```

Then I create another book like this

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Spring Boot 2"
  "authors": [
     {
        "name": "A"
     },
     {
        "name": "B"
     }
  ]
}
```

The problem is Spring JPA will create another **author "A" with id=2** in the database and **author "B" with id=3**. 
What I want is JPA use **existing author "A"** and create an **author "B" with id = 2**. 
 
**Book**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private double price;
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_author",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("books")
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**BookService**

```java
@Service

public class BookService {
    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    public List<Book> getAllBook() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Book saveBook (Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    public void deleteBook(Long id) {
        bookRepository.deleteBookById(id);
    }
}
```

**BookController**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBook() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Book>>(bookService.getAllBook(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Book> saveBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Book>(bookService.saveBook(book), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

**Author**

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("authors")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**AuthorService and AuthorController are similar to Book** 
 
**Is there any annotations or query available to fix this problem ? ? Or what is the most efficient way to do it ?** 
 
I don't want to use this solution below because I think there is a solution available in JPA, shorter and more efficient than this and I just don't know 
I illustrate this method using ChatGPT

```java
public ResponseEntity<Book> createBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        for (Author author : book.getAuthors()) {
            Optional<Author> existingAuthor = authorRepository.findOne(
                Example.of(author, ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnorePaths("id"))
            );
            if (existingAuthor.isPresent()) {
                book.addAuthor(existingAuthor.get());
            }
        }
        Book savedBook = bookService.save(book);
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/books/" + savedBook.getId())).body(savedBook);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How can JPA know if there aren't 2 authors with the same name? It can't.

If you want to 'reuse' an existing author then you have to locate and set that yourself.

A little tip, do NOT use the classes in your database model for your DTOs.

Comment: I assume that there is only 1 field name but when there are more fields such as date of birth, country, etc... then JPA keep creating new entity with every field will be the same. Can I use equals() to let JPA know there is already an existing author ?

Comment: If you have other identifiers (DoB, etc.) then they can be used in searching the database for a matching entity. You still have to search yourself, `Object.equals` can't do it.